# Angular is still doing HTTP Request without HTTPS/SSL

Tags: angular, laravel, redirect, https

I have this problem which I really don't know to deal with it. First of all, I did the website on the localhost without SSL and everything was fine. Now I added SSL and I migrated everything from HTTP to HTTP**S**.

But somehow, browsers still make the Http request even I add https:// in the URL.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class EnsureHTTPSInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor
{
    constructor()
    {

    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>
    {
        const parsedUrl = new URL(window.location.href);
        const baseUrl = parsedUrl.origin; // this will print http://example.com or http://localhost:4200

        const secureReq = request.clone
        ({
            url: (baseUrl + request.url).replace('http://', 'https://')
        });
        console.log(secureReq);

        // send the cloned, "secure" request to the next handler.
        return next.handle(secureReq);
    }
}
```

Here is my interceptor, which is doing a great job (I think..).
I thought that was a problem of .htaccess with forcing www, forcing https URL and removing trailing slash. I let you to see the .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    DirectoryIndex index.php # This line does the trick

    # Force SSL

    # If we receive a forwarded http request from a proxy...
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http [OR]

    # ...or just a plain old http request directly from the client
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =""
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

    # Redirect to https version
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
    RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

    # Force WWWW
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

And another thing is that even I remove the trailing slash from the HTTP request (in front-end, like /api/cart/products/ to -> /api/cart/products), the application still add it.

And here is how Chrome deal with it..

[image]

If you want to debug, you can enter on https://www.sarpilii.cf and after that in Magazin -> Military backpack

**IF YOU RELOAD THE LINK (ex: https://www.sarpilii.cf/produs/military-backpack )THE LARAVEL WILL SET THE DATA IN localStorage AND WILL DON'T REQUEST FROM API**

Comment: When I setup SSL, I didn't need an interceptor and thought it was all handled by the server https redirect.  I may be wrong.

Comment: @Nabel did you used --ssl when built the app?

Comment: Ah I see what I did now, I have a base url for api calls set up in my production file which is https

Answer (score 0):

Set this up as a base to your api calls rather than an interceptor

enviroment.prod

```
export const environment = {
  apiUrl: 'https://example.com/api'
}
```

In the service

```
import { environment } from 'environments/environment';
const API_URL = environment.apiUrl;
```